# Multiple wordpress installations with same plugin folder (Apache Virtualhost)

Tags: plugins, apache, virtual-hosts

I'm trying to use a single plugins folder for multiple websites to standardize my websites.
Do you know any way to use Symlinks in WordPress? In a single shared folder send the plugins to various installations using apache virtualhost?

I tried to use the Symlinks, but WordPress did not recognize Symlink as a plugin

What I have done:
Entered in var/www/mywebsite.com/wp-content/plugins

Entered the following command:

```
sudo ln -s /root/plugins/my-plugin my-plugin
```

Symlink works, but...
Nothing happened in WordPress admin panel.

Thank you

Comment: It sounds like you want a [multisite](https://www.wpbeginner.com/glossary/multisite/).

Answer (score 0):

You should put this to config files of wordpress instances

`define( 'WP_PLUGIN_DIR', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wordpress1/wp-content/plugins' );`

place it before the /* That’s all, stop editing! Happy blogging. */ line.

Comment: Thanks for the answer
I knew this solution, but the solution with Symlinks, it would allow multiple folders for plugins, and it would be something like that I want
So that it had a "generic" folder and one with the specific plugins